# Class sizes with virtual inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class abc
{
    int a;
};
class xyz : public virtual abc
{
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    abc obj;
    xyz obj1;
    cout<<endl<<sizeof(obj);
    cout<<endl<<sizeof(obj1);
    return 0;
}
```

The answers would be compiler dependent but I'm surprized when I saw this as the result

```
~/Documents/workspace/tmp ‹.rvm-›  $ ./class_sizes   

4
16
```

If I remove the virtual keyword then the size allocated is 4 and 8 respectively which is what I expected.

Why is the extra space being taken up exactly?
I suspect it is for the vptr table or something of that sorts but don't know for certain.

Comment: I'm sure you already know that the answer is extremely platform and compiler dependent, and that there's no prescription of how virtual inheritance is to be implemented. If you think about it, it's a fairly complicated beast, so you need extra space to store extra levels of indirection.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am awaiting some funky ASCII art answer which will explain this :)

Comment: @Als: I have no idea how to implement virtual inheritance, I'd have to think about it several times... and I'm sure that serious compilers would probably do it in a way more clever way than I could imagine :-) I too look forward to the ASCII art, though!

Comment: Can you check with a debugger if there is a vtable pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good article on virtual and multiple inheritance in GCC is this one *[(Internet Archive Permalink)](https://web.archive.org/web/20140827111814/http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html)*:

http://phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Yet it doesn't quite answer your question, as you are getting an output of 20 bytes out of whatever (unspecified) compiler and build settings you are using.

If you were using GCC *(under the default settings IDEone uses, at least)*, then you would be getting 12 bytes.  Which is the same thing as what it would give had you written:

```
class abc
{
    int a;
    virtual void foo() {}
};
class xyz : public abc
{
    int b;
};
```

Were you to virtually inherit from abc when it contains virtual methods:

```
class abc
{
    int a;
    virtual void foo() {}
};
class xyz : virtual public abc
{
    int b;
};
```

...then you would get 16 bytes out of GCC.

> Why is the extra space being taken up exactly? I suspect it is for the vptr table or something of that sorts but don't know for certain.

If I had to make a wild guess about your 16 byte variance: I *might* look into if your compiler's implementation of virtual inheritance treats all virtual base classes as if they had virtual methods, even if they didn't?

But I pretty much made that up.  You'll have to look further under the hood if you want to test the theory; it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: very interesting article indeed.

Comment: @HostileFork This question has been used as a duplicate reference on several occasions, any chance you might be able to elaborate on the link a bit here? In the event the link is ever not working, this answer would be missing _everything_.

Comment: @bluefeet I've added an Internet Archive permalink to make it easier in case it goes dead, but I'm afraid it isn't easy to summarize without leaving something out.  When initially offering the answer I did not go through to check if GCC did 16 bytes for this case; it doesn't, it gives 12... so the OP's question needs to be distinguished between "why does virtual inheritance add to the class size beyond the data content", vs. "why is it adding more than just a 32-bit pointer when the base class has no virtual methods".  Perhaps a poor question to use for duplicate resolution in the first place!

Comment: @HostileFork The answer is much better, thanks for fixing it up for us.  We'd gotten a few flags about quality since the question is being used as a duplicate reference.  I appreciate your attention to the matter. :)

Comment: Since your answer looks at compilers, I figured I'd provide what information I have on how MSVC does it, as a counterpart to your GCC information.  [As tested with Studio 2010, it may have changed in more recent versions.]  First, if a class has a virtual base, it stores a hidden pointer, `{vbptr}`, inside the class itself, which points to the class' vbtable (virtual base table, basically a vtable but for virtual bases); this adds `sizeof(void*)` bytes to the class.  Additionally, if no non-virtual base classes have a vtable, and the derived class declares a new virtual function that wasn't

Comment: declared in any of its virtual base classes, it creates a vtable for the class; this causes it to store another hidden pointer, `{vfptr}`, taking another `sizeof(void*)` bytes.  [From what I can tell, when a derived class can't just use a base class' vtable directly because the class declares one or more new virtual functions, MSVS will reuse the first `{vfptr}` inherited from a non-virtual base class, effectively replacing that base class' vtable with the derived class' vtable.  If the only inherited vtables belong to virtual base classes, however, the derived class will have a separate

Comment: vtable, and as such contain its own distinct `{vfptr}`.  Unless there are any other factors I'm not aware of, this means that any class with one or more virtual base classes will be at best `sizeof(void*)`, and at worst `2 * sizeof(void*)`, bytes larger than if the virtual base classes were non-virtual.  (Effectively, this means 4/8 bytes larger in 32-bit code, and 8/16 bytes larger in 64-bit code.)  [In more complex hierarchies, MSVS also tries to reuse the first non-virtual base class vbtable if necessary, similarly to its behaviour with normal vtables.]

Comment: [Note that `{vbptr}` is a pointer to the vbtable, and `{vfptr}` is a pointer to the vtable (formally, the "vftable").  The compiler tries to recycle these pointers when possible to save space, but only appears to be able to do so for normally inherited pointers.  While this makes sense for `{vbptr}` (how would you find the virtual bases if the pointer to them was stored in one of them?), it isn't as logical for `{vfptr}`s.  I suspect that the compiler at least partially reuses the same code to generate both, explaining the symmetry.]

Answer (score 3):

Virtual bases classes increase (dynamic, runtime) conversion requirements, and I suppose that the size increase are for a kind of '*pivoting ground*' to walk the (base) class hierarchy in non-ambiguous ways when doing such conversions.

In less mumbo jumbo, here is a counter example that could show what's going on:

- Using `virtual abc` **http://ideone.com/h5y7R**

  - `sizeof(xyz) == 44` (88 on 64bit arch)
- Using nonvirtual `abc` **http://ideone.com/h5y7R**

  - `sizeof(xyz) == 68` (**128** (padded) on 64bit arch)

```
#include<iostream>

class abc
{
    int x;
    virtual void t();
};

template <int unique> struct interm : virtual abc 
{
    virtual void t();
    virtual void s();
};

struct xyz : 
    /*virtual*/ interm<1>, 
    /*virtual*/ interm<2>, 
    /*virtual*/ interm<3>, 
    /*virtual*/ interm<4>,
    /*virtual*/ interm<5>, 
    /*virtual*/ interm<6>, 
    /*virtual*/ interm<7>, 
    /*virtual*/ interm<8>
{
    int b;
    virtual void t();
    virtual void s();
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(abc)       << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(interm<1>) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(xyz)       << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You'll notice a significant reduction in size when marking the `abc` base as virtual (at least on gcc). Also, note no effect when marking (any) of the `interm`ediate base classes as (non)virtual.

Comment: Well, at least it's not (XXX).

Comment: *nitpick* The difference in size as said in Q is 8 bytes not 4.

Comment: sample done, it's not really conclusive; it is still compiler dependent (in fact, probably compile-option dependent) but it should evoke some relativating ideas against the OP

Comment: **updated** thought it'd be nice to include the different numbers (32bit and 64bit) for g++

Answer (score 2):

With virtual base classes, the position of the base object relative to an instance of the derived object is not always the same, so there is a pointer that tracks that.

Comment: Provide a sample

Answer (score 2):

Non-virtual inheritance is just like object containment, given:

```
struct Derived : Base
```

It can be compiled to C++ just this way:

```
struct Derived {
    Base __base;
    // other members

    // implementation of Derived-to-Base pointer conversion
    operator Base& () { return __base; }
};
```

Virtual inheritance is like adding a level of indirection, given

```
struct Base
struct L : virtual Base
struct R : virtual Base
struct Derived : L, R
```

This can be compiled to C++ as

```
// the type L& is translated to __L_subobject&
// the type L* is translated to __L_subobject*
// lvalue of L is translated to lvalue of __L_subobject
struct __L_subobject {
    Base &__base_ref;
    __L_subobject (Base &__base_ref) 
        : __base_ref(__base_ref) {
    }
    // other members

    // pointer conversions:
    operator Base& () { return __base_ref; }
};

// a definition of variable x of type L is translated to one with type __L_complete
// but any lvalue x is translated to x.__most_derived
// (it is assumed that rvalues have been already been translated to lvalues)
struct __L_complete {
    // all virtual bases:
    Base __base;

    // derived partial subobjects:
    __L_subobject __most_derived;

    __L_complete () : __most_derived(__base) {}
};

// ... same for R ...

struct __Derived_subobject {
    __L_subobject __L;
    __R_subobject __R;
    // other members ...

    __Derived_subobject (Base &__base_ref) 
        : __L(__base_ref),
          __R(__base_ref) {
    }

    // pointer conversions:
    operator Base& () { return __L.operator Base& (); }
    operator __L_subobject& () { return __L; }
    operator __R_subobject& () { return __R; }
};

struct __Derived_complete {
    // all virtual bases:
    Base __base;

    // derived partial subobjects:
    __Derived_subobject __most_derived;

    __Derived_complete () :__most_derived(__base) {
    }
};
```

You get the idea...

Note: I have not described the vtable pointer member. (It can be used instead of the `Base&`, to have smaller classes.)

Answer (score 0):

The program when run in CodeBlocks Compiler gives 4 12 as output
This can be explained as; for base class size of object is equal to size of int.
For derived class; size of object = size of the class + size if base class + size of virtual base pointer(4).