# The size of base class object and derived class object in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Base1
{
  public:

  virtual int virt1() { return 100; }

  int data1;
};

class Derived : public Base1
{
  public:

  virtual int virt1() { return 150; }

  int derivedData;
};

int Global1( Base1 * b1 )
{
  return b1->virt1();
}

main1()
{
  Derived * d = new Derived;

  printf( "%d %d\n", d->virt1(), Global1( d ));
  printf("size: Base1:%d\n", sizeof(Base1));
  printf("size: Derived:%d\n", sizeof(Derived));
}
```

I used the above code to print out the size of the base class and derived class. I am running the code in a 64 bit machine. The output from my computer is

```
150 150
size: Base1:16
size: Derived:16
```

I also tried to print out the size of int by using sizeof(int), it's 4.

I have the following questions:

1. For the size of Base1 class, it should contain a vptr points to the
   vtable and an integer data1.  Why its size is 16 while sizeof(int)
   is 4 in my machine.
2. For the derived class, it should have the data inherited from Base1 class and an additional integer. It should have bigger size
   than Base1 class, why they are the same?
3. Besides the size of these, what's the vptr in Derived class? Will the vptr in Derived class override the vptr inherited from the Base1
   class?

Comment: Very similar question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105868/class-sizes-with-virtual-inheritance-in-c) and a link to [Memory Layout for Multiple and Virtual Inheritance](https://web.archive.org/web/20140827111814/http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html), which is a very helpful article on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For the size of Base1 class, it should contain a vptr points to the vtable and an integer data1. Why its size is 16 while sizeof(int) is 4 in my machine.

Padding to ensure proper alignment of the 8-byte pointers when `Base1`s are in a necessarily-contiguous† array.

† the C++ Standard requires that array elements be contiguous in memory, and calculates the memory address of an element at index *i* and the array's base address plus *i* times the element size

> For the derived class, it should have the data inherited from Base1 class and an additional integer. It should have bigger size than Base1 class, why they are the same?

The padding's been reclaimed for the extra `int` member.  You can observe this by outputting `d`, `&d->data1`, `&d->derivedData`.

> Besides the size of these, what's the vptr in Derived class? Will the vptr in Derived class override the vptr inherited from the Base1 class?

In implementations using pointers to virtual dispatch tables (every compiler I know of, but it's not mandated by the C++ Standard), the `Derived` class constructor(s) and destructor overwrites the "vptr" - the former writing a pointer to `Derived`'s VDT *after* the constructor body runs, the latter restoring the pointer to the `Base` VDT *before* the destructor body runs (this ensures you don't invoke `Derived` member functions on an object before or after its official lifetime).

Comment: What's the size of pointer in this case? Why it's 8-byte? Will that depend on the compiler or the machine?

Comment: @CaptainRib It's 8 bytes because you're compiling for 64 bits, and at 8 bits per byte that's 8 bytes.  Whether you can run a 64-bit OS depends on the hardware, and if both OS & hardware support 64 bit you can normally choose whether to compile a 32-bit application (with 4 byte pointers) or a 64 bit app.  Your compiler should have command line arguments to select between such targets.  Be aware that there can be limitations on using 32-bit libraries from 64-bit apps or vice versa and check your compiler/system/library docs.

Comment: @TonyD: `offsetof` cannot be used with the type in question (the behavior is undefined as the types are not *standard-layout*. A similar test can be done by printing `d`, `&d->data1` and `&d->data2`

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: true 'tis undefined... I'll edit my answer accordingly.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD Are you sure the padding will be reclaimed for the etrax data member int in derived class object? If so, would there be any problem if you copy the object to another object, say another derived object? According to another friend, he said derived should have the size 24 because it's 16+4+padding.

Comment: @CaptainRib "Are you sure the padding will be reclaimed...?" - are you sure you saw output "size: Base1:16 size: Derived:16"?  What else *could* that mean? ;-P  Did you try outputting the addresses of the object and data members to confirm how they're laid out?  (Yes, I'm sure).  *"If so, would there be any problem if you copy the object to another object, say another derived object?"* - as in `Derived a = ...; Derived b; b = a;`?  No problem - the default `operator=` will copy both `int`s happily - what kind of problem were you worried about?

Comment: @TonyD Hi Tony, thanks for the response firstly. The reason why I have the doubt is because of this blog. http://robina.blog.com/2013/07/09/c-1-class-vmf-inheritance/  It printed 16, 24 instead. (If I'm didn't misunderstand it).

Comment: @CaptainRib "It printed 16, 24 instead." - what did?  The blog doesn't seem to mention anything printing 16 and 24, nor even have any mention of size let alone `sizeof`.  Anyway, the C++ Standard doesn't require the compiler to give both structures the same size, nor does it prohibit it... it's a spatial optimisation that's optional and my answer is explaining what's evidently happened to produce the output you described in your question, not promising the same kind of optimisation will always be made by every C++ compiler.

Comment: @TonyD It seems that I sent the wrong link. Sorry pal. Anyway, your really solved most of my problems. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that decide the size of an object of a class in C++.

These factors are:

- Size of all non-static data members
- Order of data members
- Byte alignment or byte padding
- Size of its immediate base class
- The existence of virtual function(s) (Dynamic polymorphism using virtual functions).
- Compiler being used
- Mode of inheritance (virtual inheritance)

When I compile your code on MVSC 2010, x64 bits. This is the result of memory layout:

```
class Base1 size(16):
    +---
 0  | {vfptr}
 8  | data1
    | <alignment member> (size=4)
    +---

Base1::$vftable@:
    | &Base1_meta
    |  0
0   | &Base1::virt1
```

Base1::virt1 this adjustor: 0

```
   class Derived    size(24):
    +---
    | +--- (base class Base1)
0   | | {vfptr}
8   | | data1
    | | <alignment member> (size=4)
    | +---
16  | derivedData
    | <alignment member> (size=4)
    +---

Derived::$vftable@:
    | &Derived_meta
    |  0
 0  | &Derived::virt1
```

You should read more about vTable, virtual function, byte alignment of class/struct.
Here, some links can help you. Hope it helpful to you:

Determine the size of class object: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/size_of_class_object.html

Memory layout: http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html